# How to get previous url with hash parameter in laravel

Tags: laravel, hash

I have a url something like:
http://www.example.net/books/#page=2&offset=3

that will display all the books with pagination.
How do I get the previous URL with all the hash params in laravel if the user has clicked to one of the book?

Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with Laravel or PHP. It's browser behaviour. Server-side framework cannot 'know' what the previous URL was because life cycle of a server-side framework (besides websockets) is a single request. You can do this via JS if you wish

Comment: Do you update the hash or the full url?

Comment: storing the requests in session would work i think if done properly

Comment: @DenisMysenko how do I do this in JS?

Comment: @SvenB the hash will be updated if for example on page 3 etc. So if I click to one of the book, say, will go to http://www.example.net/books/detail/123, how do I get the previous URL with complete hash param

Comment: @RyanVincent Why isn't the book id in the url is because http://www.example.net/books/#page=2&offset=3 is the page to list all the books with pagination. Why I need this is because on the book detail page, there is a 'back to listing' button. The button should just a link back to book listing with hash param

Comment: Do you really need to use hash/fragment? It would be easier if you just pass `page` and `offset` as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some magic by injecting it with javascript at every change